# Value not updating when taken from PHP file in a loop

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm trying to repeatedly call a function in another PHP file that querys a database. The idea is that when new values are entered into the database, the loop is there to pick them up.

The call and loop seems to work. But the new calues in the database aren't picked up.

Since the call is done in JS, I have tried using XMLHttpRequest() but to no success.

The call sets the value of "duration". It's this value I want to have updated whenever the loop goes by.

the "first()" is located in the "api.php".

```
<?php
  include 'api.php';
?>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

  var duration;

  (function theLoop (i) {
  setTimeout(function () {
  if (--i) {          
  theLoop(i);  

         duration = <?php echo first("aaa"); ?>

         if(duration > 29){

               window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';

         }
         else if(duration < 29){
         }                   
  } 

 }, 3000);
})(100);

});
</script>
```

Comment: My poor eyes >.< Why do you not just get the response from an ajax call? value changes->send->handle->return updated value->do something->repeat

Comment: Don't stare long into the abyss! This was the closest to working. When I tried Ajax I guess I wasn't doing it right. An example of an Ajax call to another file with a function like this would be great. I haven't found anything I myself can understand I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that the PHP code will only run once when the page is loading and will give you HTML code. The JS in the page will have `duration` always refering to the value from the first time the PHP code runs.

You really need to use AJAX for this and create a new PHP page to call that will run everytime a request is made.

[jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)
JS:

```
// HERE YOU DO A AJAX GET REQUEST
$.get({
   // PASS VALUES TO THE PHP
   data: {
      "first": "aaa"
   },
   url: THE URL TO YOUR PHP PAGE,
   // THE SUCCESS FUNCTION IS WHAT WILL RUN WHEN THE GET COMPLETES SUCCESSFULLY
   success: function(duration) {
     // DO WHAT YOU WERE GOING TO DO
     if(duration > 29){
           window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';

     }
     else if(duration < 29){
     }            
   },
   error: A FUNCTION TO HANDLE WHAT TO DO IF THE REQUEST DOES NOT COMPLETE
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
   include 'api.php';

   // GET THE PARAMETER FROM THE JS
   $firstParam = $_GET["first"]
   echo first(firstParam);
?>
```

Comment: Actually, there is another part to this that I forgot. "aaa" is actually a dynamic value that needs to be sent along with the $get since it's a value that goes in the function "first(----);". Is there a way to pass this along with the Ajax call?

Comment: You can use `$_GET` in the PHP and the `data` attribute of $.get.
See updated answer.

Comment: That was the last piece. Thank you!